Issue with testing an asynchronous FastAPI application
I'm trying to figure out testing FastAPI with pytest. My application is asynchronous, which adds some complexity. Could you tell me if my conftest.py file is set up correctly?
DATABASE_URL = (
    "postgresql+asyncpg://"
    f"{settings.POSTGRES_USER}:{settings.POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@"
    f"{settings.POSTGRES_HOST}:{settings.POSTGRES_PORT}/"
    f"{settings.POSTGRES_DB_TEST}"
)

engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL, echo=True)
async_session = sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession)


async def override_get_db() -> AsyncGenerator[AsyncSession, None]:
    async with async_session() as session:
        yield session


app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = override_get_db


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="session")
async def prepare_database():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)
    yield
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.drop_all)


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def event_loop(request):
    """Create an instance of the default event loop for each test case."""
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop_policy().new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()


client = TestClient(app)


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
async def ac() -> AsyncGenerator[AsyncClient, None]:
    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://test") as ac:
        yield ac

Here's the test function, and I'm encountering an error. Please let me know how to set up basic testing for my case using pytest. I see that people implement it differently in each GitHub repository.
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_country(ac: AsyncClient):
    response = await ac.get("/api/v1/countries/1")

    response_data = response.json()

    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response["name"] == "Test Country"


error:
FAILED tests/test_country.py::test_get_country - AttributeError: 'async_generator' object has no attribute 'get'

I looked at the FastAPI documentation, and it uses fake_db instead of a real database. The article on asynchronous testing is brief. I don’t have problems testing simple functions like a health check that just returns a string, but I encounter issues when I need to run integration tests using a test database.

Have you installed pytest-asyncio?

@M.O. ofc pytest = "^8.3.2"
pytest-asyncio = "^0.23.8"  httpx = "^0.27.0"
